# UICollectionView Within Last UITableViewCell AND Congruent Scrolling? How?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm racking my head over this one, I know this has to be possible but after going over every bit of documentation I still can't come up with something that works well.

Basically, I have a UICollectionView in the LAST cell of a UITableView. What I want to happen is, only when the UITableView is totally scrolled to the bottom, can the UICollectionView in it's last cell start scrolling. And, if the TableView offset reaches the bottom of the CollectionView's tableviewcell during a drag / pan, any additional dragging of the current  table view drag / pan should effect the collection view instead of the table view.

Also, when the collection view is scrolling, if a user starts scrolling on the collection view, if the collection view reaches the top of it's scroll (Content Y offset of 0 or less), and additional scrolling of the current pan/drag gesture in affect should cause the containing table view to scroll up.

The reason I want to achieve this effect, is because the table view cell above the last cell containing the collection view, contains a UISegmentControl that toggles the contents of the UICollectionView, and I want the user to be able to toggle this segment at any time while scrolling in the CollectionView. Meaning the collection view has to scroll but the parent table view needs to not scroll..

I've tried playing with the gesture recognizers, and doing something with

```
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

This gets me halfway there, I can use a flag to return yes/no to this method if the collection view is to scroll into a negative offset (Past it's top offset) or if the table view has reached the end of it's total scroll.. I get sort of close to what I want to achieve, but if I scroll up slowly on the collection view, it doesn't fire the simultaneous recognizer, same happens if I scroll down on the table view too slowly.

Another issue is, I do NOT want the collection view to bounce. However setting bounces to NO totally prevents the simultaneous recognizer to fire at all. I even tried setting content offset to CGPointZero on the collection view in it's viewDidScroll if it's y offset were to dip below zero. This also doesn't work and prevents the simultaneous method from firing...

Does anyone have any idea what to do? Or something to point me in the right direction?

UPDATE -

Still trying at this, I've made little progress towards the behavior I'm trying to achieve. I've messed with toggling userInteractionEnabled in the viewDidScroll method, as have I tried in willBeginDragging. The same with scrollEnabled property.. No luck :( I get a behavior similar to what I want with this, however the parent view will not scroll up until the user lets off the screen and attempts to scroll again..

UPDATE -

Is there anyway to transition the panGestureRecognizer currently handling scroll events DURING scrolling? If I could transition the scroll handler from the child to the parent while still scrolling this would solve my issue. I've looked through apple's gesture related and uiscrollview related documentation and can't find anything close to doing that.

UPDATE -

Just got done trying something like this..

```
- (CGPoint)maxParentContentOffset
{
    return CGPointMake(0, self.parentScrollView.contentSize.height - self.frame.size.height - 44);
}

- (void)parentScrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)parentScrollView
{
    if (self.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        self.parentScrollView.contentOffset = [self maxParentContentOffset];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:scrollView.superview];
    if (translation.y < 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void) {
            self.parentScrollView.contentOffset = [self maxParentContentOffset];
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

However there is a problem... for some reason I keep getting a bad access error on the following method

```
- (void)parentScrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)parentScrollView
    {
        if (self.contentOffset.y > 0) {
            self.parentScrollView.contentOffset = [self maxParentContentOffset];
        }
    }
```

Specifically setting the content offset. Which is really strange, because with breakpoints I'm seeing parentScrollView and self as being set. I'm wondering if it's not a bad access but it's getting trapped in an infinite loop for some reason? Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I have a UICollectionView with three cells of varied heights (100, 50 for the two). In the bottom-most cell, I have a UITableView with 100 of table view cells. I also need to scroll seamlessly on collectionview friend and then quickly switch to tableview scrolling (and vice-versa when scrolling up). Any help here would be really appreciated. Do you have the gist file of how you fixed this in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out after a good 8 hours.. I had a confliction due to infinite setting of the parent scroll view offset, since I had multiple objects that were of the same class that received a call whenever their parent view scrolled, both trying to set the same parent view offset to zero, which caused the other class to see scroll changing, and calling their method to change offset, and the process happening infinitely causing a crash.

This code however, solved everything and functions exactly as I was desiring. Hopefully this helps anyone else in the future looking to get congruent scrolling between a parent and child scroll view.

```
- (CGPoint)maxParentContentOffset
{
    return CGPointMake(0, self.parentScrollView.contentSize.height - self.frame.size.height - 44);
}

- (void)parentScrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)parentScrollView
{
    if (self.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.isDragging) {
        self.parentScrollView.contentOffset = [self maxParentContentOffset];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:scrollView.superview];
    if (translation.y < 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^(void) {
            self.parentScrollView.contentOffset = [self maxParentContentOffset];
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though you may manage to make it work now, embedding a collection view inside a table view (both `UIScrollView` subclasses) is not a good idea and it will bug as soon as apple modifies their implementation.

Try to migrate to a single `UICollectionView` layout. After all there's nothing you can't achieve with a collection view that a table view can.

---

Separate your "table view" and "collection view" in two (or more) collection view sections, then implement `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` differently according to the `indexPath.section`.

To make it table view-like you'll want to return frames whose `width` are the same as the collection view.

If your layout is simpler then you could use a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (maybe your already are) and implement `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` as described above.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Do you have any references as to how to go about migrating a table view with X potentially dynamic tabale view cells that are all different to a collection view?

Answer (score 0):

In an application that I've worked, we needed something close to that, we wanted to have a `uitableview` inside the first cell of another `uitableview,` which should be scrollable (you can check the app [here](http://fulltime-app.com/))

Our approach was quite different, and we thought about doing it your way, but that way was a bit overkill for the time we had, and needed too much custom control instead of using what apple already gives us.
I'll share our method just for you to have another way to solve your problem, since I can't figure out what is wrong in that method call.

On the outer tableview's datasource lifecycle, we were able to know how our inner table view would be, allowing us to feed our inner table view with all the data, which would then gave us the `total content size of the inner table view`.

With this info, and since we knew (and in your case, you know) the actual cell where the inner table view would be placed, we `make that cell's height equal to the height of the inner tableview content size`. With this, the inner table view is 'totally visible'(in your case, the collection view) inside the outer table view cell, but since the cell is so big, it looks like we are scrolling the inner table view when we are simply scrolling a really big, special, cell. 
And it won't bounce, if you don't want it too.

In our case, this worked, and the implementation was pretty straight forward. 
In your case, and since you have a `UISegmentedController`, you should do a `beginUpdates` `endUpdates`  and a 'reloadData', upon press in the `UISegmenedController`, in your outer table view in order to be able to recalculate the collection view's content size and resize the last cell, but that is pretty straight forward.

I know I'm not answering your question, but this method allowed us to achieve something so similar in such a fast and straight forward way that I thought it was worth sharing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The funny thing is, I actually used this initial approach. However there is a problem, which is exactly why I'm trying to get the way I'm doing it now working. With showing the full view height of the inner tableview, you lose the ability to Reuse tableviewcells, as all cells of that tableview are loaded initially, since the tableview only knows that it's full contents are showing based on it's height, and not where it is relative to the scroll of the parent. I need this specific CollectionView to scroll and not be all visible as it infinitely loads in new content during scroll.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, in our case it works since our inner table view's size is fixed, and we know it while launching the app. 
Just as one more idea, since we also thought about this for another project, have you considered using only a UICollectionView with the first item's layout looking like UITableViewCell's?

Comment: A component like that in the open source world would be pretty cool if  it gets dynamic enough. Just an idea.

Comment: Got it working :) Check my post :) Pretty light on code too, just took some figuring out

Comment: Ahah! nice! Gotta try it :D